# Bash - Convert Italian date in numeric format

Tags: bash, date

On my system, if I ask `date` for month I obtain:

```
$ date +%B
febbraio
```

in which "febbraio" is the Italian name for "february".

If I try to convert a date (with the Italian name for the month) to numeric format I obtain an error:

```
$ date -d "6 febbraio 2021" "+%d/%m/%Y"
date: data "6 febbraio 2021" non valida
```

which means that date is not valid.

If I change "febbraio" to "february", everything is ok:

```
$ date -d "6 february 2021" "+%d/%B/%Y"
06/febbraio/2021
```

Is it possible to convert to the numeric format a date in which the month is expressed in Italian?

Comment: I suggest to replace first italian words with `bash`, `sed` or `awk` to english words.

Comment: @Cyrus that is the solution I arranged for now. :)

Comment: Not possible without preprocessing the datetime string. GNU date can parse `january`, `jan`, `jan.`, etc. (and `sept`, all case-insensitive), but not `febbraio`, `luty`, `февраль`, or `şubat`.